# Is my understanding of CW complexes correct?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, definition, cw-complexes

I'm very new to algebraic topology and am trying to wrap my head around [CW complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex). My main sources are Allen Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Algebraic-Topology-Allen-Hatcher/dp/0521795400) and these [online notes](https://www.math.ksu.edu/%7Ehansen/CWcomplexes.pdf) by Soren Hansen. I outline my current understanding below and would be very grateful if you could take a look and point out any mistakes or details that I've skirted over.

---

For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$, we denote the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (w.r.t. the Euclidean norm) by $D^n$. First of all, it is important to note that since $\text{Int}(D^n)$ is homeomorphic to whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have that $\text{Int}(D^m)$ and $\text{Int}(D^n)$ are homeomorphic $\iff$ $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are homeomorphic $\iff$ $m=n$.

We define a *cell* to be a topological space $X$ that is homeomorphic to $\text{Int}(D^n)$ for some (necessarily unique by the previous paragraph) $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$, which we call its *dimension*. We refer to a cell of dimension $n$ as an $n$-*cell*.

A *cell decomposition* of a topological space $X$ is a partition of $X$ into a family of cells $\mathcal{E}\equiv\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$. (By a 'partition', I mean that the cells $e_{\alpha}$ are non-empty, mutually disjoint and cover the whole of $X$.) The $n$-*skeleton* of $X$ is the union of all cells of dimension no greater than $n$, which we denote by $X^n$.

We now define a *CW complex* to be a Hausdorff space $X$ with a cell decomposition $\mathcal{E}\equiv\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ satisfying

(i) For each $n$-cell $e\in\mathcal{E}$, there exists a continuous map $\Phi_e:D^n\to X$ that maps $\text{Int}(D^n)$ homeomorphically onto $e$ and the boundary $\partial D^n\equiv S^{n-1}$ (not necessarily homeomorphically) into the $(n-1)$-skeleton $X^{n-1}$.

(ii) The closure $\overline{e}$ of each cell $e\in\mathcal{E}$ intersects only finitely many other cells in $\mathcal{E}$.

(iii) A subset $V$ of $X$ is closed if and only if $V\cap\overline{e}$ is closed for each cell $e\in\mathcal{E}$.

---

My main concern here is that there are many different definitions that I have seen which do not look alike, and it feels like I'm missing something. Is there a more intuitive way of thinking about CW complexes? Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Take first some disjoint points, the 0-skeleton $X_0$. Then we take some closed 1-cells and glue each 1-cell along its boundary $S^0$, two distinct points, via a continuous map on $X_0$. Then we have a 1-skeleton $X_1$ which looks like a graph. Then we take some closed 2-cells and glue each 2-cell along its boundary $S^1$, the unit circle, via a continuous map on $X_1$. Then we have a 2-skeleton $X_2$. The same for higher dimensional cells. Note that the interior of the glued cells is not touched, so the glueing maps are homeomorphisms on the interiors. We get a CW-complex.

Comment: I kind of get the inductive argument you describe, which is similar to the definition given in Hatcher's book, yet it does seem quite different to what I have outlined in my question (mostly based on the online notes I cited). Does it look right to you?

Comment: I think that are two different view points: one view point is somehow constructive, how to build up a CW complex. The other viewpoint is that the space $X$ is already given and we find that this topological space can be quasi viewed as a result of inductively gluing cells together.

Comment: The equivalence of these is also discussed in Hatcher's appendix.